# Delegates.observable for anonymous functions in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am doing something weird but I have a fleeting feeling it should be possible.

Is the below possible with Kotlin ? (It compiles but doesn't work)

```
 var delegatedProp: (Int) -> Unit by Delegates.observable({ a-> Unit }) { _, _, newVal ->
        //This is never raised
        //Secondly how should I access the given Int ?
        //newVal.a doesn't seem to compile
    }
```

I was off the idea that once I invoke delegatedProp(10) , the observable would invoke and I would be able to access newVal.a.

This compiles successfully but the observable is never invoked

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with that construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second lambda will be invoked *when you set `delegatedProp`*, i.e.

```
x.delegatedProp = { print(it) }
```

(`{ print(it) }` is just an example of something of type `(Int) -> Unit`). And `newVal` will be the function you set the property to, in this case `{ print(it) }`. So it doesn't have an `.a`.

If you want to do something when invoking `delegatedProp(10)`, you just... put those actions into the function:

```
val delegatedProp: (Int) -> Unit = { a -> /* do whatever you wanted to do with newVal.a */ }
```

If you want `delegatedProp` to be a `var`, but to keep doing your "extra" actions whatever it's assigned to, the easiest way may be a custom getter:

```
var delegatedProp: (Int) -> Unit = { a -> Unit }
    get() = { a ->
        /* whatever you want to do with a */
        field(a)
    }
```

Or a setter: it wouldn't create a new lambda each time it's accessed, but either duplicates a bit of code or needs to be explicitly set at least once and not only initialized.